# How to manage state in a react button component on submit

Tags: reactjs

I am very new to React, and I wonder how I can manage state to display a text depending on how the submit of a bootstrap form / button goes ? The problem is that I want to set an initial state in the constructor, but the component re-renders when there is changes and thus resets state to the initial state, because the constructor is called again. Hooks ? How to go on about this :

´´´

```js
 class InputForm extends React.Component {

    constructor(props) {

       /** So this will just reset state when the component is re-rendered */
       this.state = {
          formState: text.UNPROCESSED;
       };
    }

    getErrorText() {
       if (this.state.formState === text.ERROR) {
          return "Some text"; 
       }

       /** Thus, this will always return */
       return "Some other text"; 
    };

    handleSubmit(event){

      /** For illustration */
      this.setState({ formState: text.ERROR });  

    };

 render() {
   return (   
    <div class="inputForm">
    <Form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
    <Form.Group controlId="formBasic">
        <h1>>Submit here</h1>
        <Form.Control type="email" placeholder="Enter email" />
         <Form.Text className="text-muted">
            <div>{this.getErrorText()}</div>
        </Form.Text>
    </Form.Group>
    <center><Button variant="primary" type="submit">
        Submit
    </Button></center>
    </Form>
    </div>
)};
```

´´´

Comment: It won't reset if the component re-renders, constructor called once per component lifetime, I guess what you want is `e.preventDefault` when submitting a form.

Comment: ok, so the problem is that the component is re-initialized ? I will edit

Comment: What is "e.preventDefault" ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whenever you call a function from Form always add `event.preventDefault()` in the beginning to avoid browser from submitting the form which is it's default behaviour.

```
handleSubmit(event){
      event.prevenyDefault();
      this.setState({ formState: text.ERROR });  

    };
```

Here us the small example demonstrating state upadate using onSubmit using hooks:

```
import React, {useState} from "react";
import "./styles.css";

export default function App() {
  const [text, setText ] = useState("");
  const [submitText, setSubmitText] = useState ()
  
  handleSubmit =(event)=>{
    event.preventDefault();
    setSubmitText(text);
  }
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
        <p> submitted text: {submitText}</p>
        <input 
          onChange={(e)=> setText(e.target.value)}
          />
      </form>
    </div>
  );
}
```

[Codesandbox Link](https://codesandbox.io/s/compassionate-sky-ngwmr?from-embed=&file=/src/App.js)

You can read more adout default action here : [Default Browser Actions](https://javascript.info/default-browser-action#:%7E:text=There%20are%20many%20default%20browser%20actions%3A&text=submit%20%E2%80%93%20clicking%20an%20%3Cinput%20type,a%20field%2C%20or%20other%20actions.)

Answer (score 1):

> when there is changes and thus resets state to the initial state,
> because the constructor is called again

First of all and foremost important thing you should remember is that `constructor` is called only once and does not re-called unless component unmounts and re-mounts.
Secondly try using `componentDidUpdate` lifecycle, if you are saying that state is not updating then inside `componentDidUpdate` your `formState` won't reflect **text.ERROR** but I thing it will reflect. Just debug your code using **consoles** and you will find the cause of this problem.

> **Solution:**
>
> Bind your **this.handleSubmit** inside constructor before passing it
> to `form` tag as a reference. If you check browser's console it will
> be throwing error for setState is not defined because of JS's `this`.
> Or else define your `handleSubmit` outside constructor using arrow
> syntax like this:

```
const handleSubmit = (event) => {
     /** For illustration */
     this.setState({ formState: text.ERROR });  
};
```

or do some amendments inside your constructor like this:

```
constructor(props) {

       /** So this will just reset state when the component is re-rendered */
       this.state = {
          formState: text.UNPROCESSED;
       };

       this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
    }

    getErrorText() {
       if (this.state.formState === text.ERROR) {
          return "Some text"; 
       }

       /** Thus, this will always return */
       return "Some other text"; 
    };

    handleSubmit(event){

      /** For illustration */
      this.setState({ formState: text.ERROR });  

    };
```